# Rewriting for loop with jax.lax.scan

Tags: python, jax, google-jax

I'm having troubles understanding the [JAX documentation](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.lax.scan.html?highlight=lax.scan). Can somebody give me a hint on how to rewrite simple code like this with **`jax.lax.scan`**?

```
numbers = numpy.array( [ [3.0, 14.0], [15.0, -7.0], [16.0, -11.0] ])
evenNumbers = 0
for row in numbers:
      for n in row:
         if n % 2 == 0:
            evenNumbers += 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a solution should demonstrate the concepts rather than optimize the example shown, the function to be `jax.lax.scan`ned must match the expected signature and any dynamic condition has to be replaced with `jax.lax.cond`. The code below is the closest to the original I could think of, but please be aware that I'm anything but an jaxpert.

```
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp

def f(carry, row):

    even = 0
    for n in row:
        even += jax.lax.cond(n % 2 == 0, lambda: 1, lambda: 0)

    return carry + even, even

numbers = jnp.array([[3.0, 14.0], [15.0, -7.0], [16.0, -11.0]])
jax.lax.scan(f, 0, numbers)
```

Output

```
(DeviceArray(2, dtype=int32, weak_type=True),
 DeviceArray([1, 0, 1], dtype=int32, weak_type=True))
```